# Nodejs express.js - how to render raw html in view

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm making a personal blog using Node.js and Express. I'm saving every post with two fields, a title and content.

Inside the content I will have a few paragrahs and Images, therefore I was thinking to write html inside and then display that content as raw html, for instance:

My content:

```
<p>paragrah 1</p>
<p>paragrah 2</p>
<p>paragrah 3</p>
<img src=""></img>
```

How can I render to look nice and don't show that html tag? Is there any package to render this kind of things?

Answer (score 0):

This source helped me to render using templates:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application
I used EJS as a render template. Jade, and handlebars are other options.

As a clarification, you DO want to display the text in HTML format, but not show the tag?

Comment: I have a model called Post with two columns, title and content. Inside my content I will have really long text which I would like to use html tag to style that content a bit. But if a display it now, the browser shows the html tags as text and not as html. Di I clarify better?

Comment: Yes I understand now, it's displaying on the page with the tags, and you just want the styled content. When I render a page through express using EJS, anything contained in an HTML tag is rendered on the page as styled content. I liked how easy EJS was to set up as well, I'd suggest it.

Comment: I've already installed EJS. <%- %> did the trick. Before I was using <%= post.content %> which didn't evaluate the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to render the content not-escaped.

Usually, by default templating engines render content in a safe way, i.e they will escape any html content. For example, if you try to render a html link tag, a safe render will change `<a>` into `&lt;a&gt;`. When the browser receives the escape content, it will show you visually `<a>`. But semantically for the browser it's not a link

[Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) is a popular rendering engine for nodejs, like [EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/), the one mentioned previously. To do a safe render with Handlebars, you need to use double-brackets `{{mycontenthere}}`. To do a non-safe render with Handlebars (i.e, what you want), you need to use triple-brackets `{{{myContentHere}}}`

I have put together a [skeleton for Express and Handlebars](https://github.com/jklepatch/kangaroojs) on github where Handlebars in already setup with Express.

- In your controller file: `res.render('mytemplate.hbs', {myContent: myContent});`
- In your template file: `{{{myContent}}}`